# Mutt Composition - When composing an email prevent "CC:" Question

Tags: mutt

When I press "m" to compose an email in mutt I am asked "to:", "cc:" and "subject:". Can I select the fields to be asked, for example, only "to:" and "subject:"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable asking for “Cc:” by unsetting the `askcc` setting; in your `~/.muttrc`:

```
unset askcc
```

Comment: perfect, any idea on how to do a macros for that? For example, with "m" I do the normal compose and with "M" I do without "CC:"? Thanks in any case

Comment: Note that the default in mutt for this setting is "no", so OP has presumably explicitly enabled `askcc` in their `.muttrc`.